# App crashes when trying to load data from a singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I have `ViewControllerA` and `ViewControllerB`. In each I have this property

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *racersArray;
```

In ViewControllerA I'm filling the `racersArray` with custom objects. When I press the burger button on my `ViewControllerA`, I store my filled `_racersArray` to singleton array and then I send a notification to `ViewControllerB` that my `_racesArray` content is yet in singleton array. I use this method:

```
- (void)burgerMenu
{
    [ArraySingleton sharedManager].sharedArray = _racersArray;

    // Send a notification to burger menu view controller to reload it's tableview
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReloadTableViewData" object:nil];
    // Opens the burger menu
    [self.frostedViewController presentMenuViewController];
}
```

In `ViewControllerB` when I receive the notification, I call this method:

```
- (void)reloadTableviewData
{
    _racersArray = [ArraySingleton sharedManager].sharedArray;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

But after I try to load the data from singleton array to `_racersArray`, my app crashes with error:

```
[Racer count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe46aef7330
2016-10-03 23:58:44.091 Stopwatch[67948:6727940] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Racer count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe46aef7330'
```

This is how my singleton looks

```
@synthesize sharedArray;

+ (ArraySingleton *)sharedManager
{
    static ArraySingleton *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[ArraySingleton alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        sharedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"picee", nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Which line does the exception occur on? The exception says that you invoked the `count` method on an instance of `Racer`, so somewhere you seem to have assigned a `Racer` to a reference that you are treating as a reference to an array

Comment: the error says that Racer class doesn't have count method, check if you're actually calling count on the array.

Comment: It occurs in `reloadTableviewData` method on line `_racersArray = [ArraySingleton sharedManager].sharedArray;`. I only call the `count` method in `numberOfRowsInSection` method like return `[_racersArray count];`.

Comment: The error can't happen on the line `_racersArray = [ArraySingleton sharedManager].sharedArray;`. Please point out the actual line causing the exception.

Comment: And please update your question with the declaration for the `sharedArray` property.

Comment: I have a breakpoint there and it crashes right after that breakpoint. Is it any other way how I can figure out where it crashes?

Comment: @doe Add an exception breakpoint in the breakpoint navigator

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks, it crashes in `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)sectionIndex` method in `ViewControllerB` on the `return [[_racersArray objectAtIndex:sectionIndex] count];` line. According to Xcode array should contain everything that it's supposed to contain, but it crashes anyway

Comment: @Paulw11 now I can see the most stupid mistake I've ever made. That line is `[[_racersArray objectAtIndex:sectionIndex] count]` but it's supposed to be `[[[_racersArray objectAtIndex:sectionIndex] times] count]` because there is an array in it. Singletons are new for me so I was confused and didn't pay closer attention to the basic things. Thanks for being my rubber duck. :) Thank you so much!!

Comment: You should use `self.racersArray` rather than `_racersArray` unless you have a specific reason to bypass the setter/getter.  Also, copying an array reference out of a singleton kind of defeats the purpose of using a singleton.  You should probably refer to the singleton array directly and declare the array property of your singleton as `copy`. Finally, even better would be to implement your own `setter` for the array property of your singleton and in that method issue the NSNotification rather than relying on the setting object to do it

Comment: Thank you for all advices, I am going to change the code right now. :)